# Question about play-testers for prototyping off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm taking [this game design course on edX](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-game-design-mitx-11-126x#.VSaWyHXN9b4) (which, by the way, is excellent) and they emphasized the importance of prototyping, and **getting new/fresh people to try your prototypes.**

Is it valid to ask on GD.SE "where can I find prototype play-testers for my games?"

There's a similar question [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15020/how-do-i-recruit-beta-testers) about beta testers, which appears to be closed, then re-opened.

I thought about asking people directly in chat if they are interested, but it seems to be a small pool of users who recurringly visit (not, as required, a pool of fresh people all the time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "where can I find playtesters" would qualify as being off-topic in the sense that it is a list-of question.

As I understand it, your linked example question was re-opened because it was changed to ask about a strategy rather than asking about a list of locations (I still don't think it's a great question, which is why I assume I voted to close it originally).

Comment: I figured as much. Thanks for your opinion.